# Apache's httpclient blocking on socketread even with soTimeout set

Tags: java, httpclient, blocking

I have to fetch a few html pages over the wire, and I am using apache's httpclient from the http-components package. I have set the connectionTimeout, soTimeout as 5000 milliseconds as well as turned of redirection to false, but the code seems to get blocked in socketread function.

The specific url's which are blocked are given below:
http://high.lrn.fm
http://gotradioaac04.lbdns-streamguys.com

Could anyone give me any advice as to how to prevent the thread to block on socket read operation of the httpclient

My code is given below for the reference

```
public class HTTPDataDownloader {

    private static final Logger logger          = Logger.getLogger(HTTPDataDownloader.class);
    private int                 soTimeout;                                                      // ms
    private int                 connTimeout;                                                    // ms
    private HttpParams          httpParameters;
    private HttpClient          httpClient;
    private static final String HTTP_CONTENT    = "text/html";

    public HTTPDataDownloader( int soTimeout, int connTimeout ) {
        this.soTimeout = soTimeout;
        this.connTimeout = connTimeout;
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, connTimeout);
        // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
        // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, soTimeout);
        HttpConnectionParams.setStaleCheckingEnabled(httpParameters, false);
        HttpConnectionParams.setLinger(httpParameters, 5);
        httpParameters.setParameter("http.protocol.handle-redirects",false);
        HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(httpParameters, false);
        //HttpClientParams.setConnectionManagerTimeout(httpParameters, 500);

        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    }

    private void setRetryHandler() {
        HttpRequestRetryHandler retryHandler = new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(2, true);

        //httpClient.setHttpRequestRetryHandler(retryHandler);
        //httpClient.getParams().setParameter(HttpParams, arg1)
    }

    // takes the url, make the connection and fetch the data
    public String fetch( String urlname ) {
        urlname = formatURL(urlname);
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet();
        try {
            httpget.setURI(new URI(urlname));
        } catch ( URISyntaxException e ) {
            logger.error(e.toString());
            return null;
        }

        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        InputStream instream = null;
        try {
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            if ( entity != null ) {

                String contentType = entity.getContentType().getValue();
                HeaderElementIterator it = new BasicHeaderElementIterator(
                                                                          httpResponse.headerIterator(HTTP.CONN_KEEP_ALIVE));
            /*  while (it.hasNext()) {
                    HeaderElement he = it.nextElement();
                    String param = he.getName(); 
                    String value = he.getValue();
                    if (value != null && param.equalsIgnoreCase("timeout")) {
                        System.out.println(value + urlname);
                    }
                }*/
                if ( contentType != null && contentType.indexOf(HTTP_CONTENT) >= 0 ) {
                    instream = entity.getContent();
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
                    String line;
                    String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");

                    while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null )
                        content.append(line + newLine);
                    logger.info("Downloaded: " + httpget.getURI().toString());
                    return content.toString();
                }
            }
        }
        catch ( ClientProtocolException e ) {       
            logger.info("ClientProtocolException: " + e + " " + urlname);
        } catch ( ConnectTimeoutException e ) {
            logger.info("ConnectionTimeoutException: " + e + " " + urlname);
        } catch ( SocketTimeoutException e ) {
            logger.info("SocketTimeoutException: " + e + " " + urlname);
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            logger.info("IOException: " + e + " " + urlname);
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            logger.equals("Exception: " + e + " " + urlname);
        } finally {
            httpget.abort();    
            try {               
                if (instream != null)
                    instream.close(); 
            } catch ( IOException e ) { }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: The first URL is returning HTTP 302 (Moved Permanently).  Could this be relevant?

Comment: yes even i checked that...that means that the url have moved and needs to be redirected...but i turned off redirection os think this should be handled...but the other url is what causing hte problem

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution or workaround for this? I am having the exact same problem. It only happens when I try to fetch from Shoutcast URLs.

Comment: "The code seems to get blocked in socketread function". What's your evidence for that?

Answer (score 0):

I have met the problem too, because the httpclient.execute thread does not release the connection. You can try to add two line after getting the response:

```
httpget.releaseConnection();
httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```